# PHP mysql fetch array error

Tags: php, mysql

```
  Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\arun\login.php on line 9
```

**Code:**

```
$db_select = mysql_select_db('my_db', $con);
$username = $_GET['username'];
$password = $_GET['password'];
$role = $_GET['role'];
$result = mysql_query("Insert into  table1(Username,Password,Role) values (Username='$username', Password='$password',Role='$role') ",$con);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

if ( mysql_error() )
 {
  die ( mysql_error());
}
$row_PK = mysql_fetch_assoc($row);
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: did you googling how to insert data to database in php ? this is really effortless question. put some effort from your end then come to us

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid - No, not really

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
$result = mysql_query("Insert into  table1(Username,Password,Role) values (Username='$username', Password='$password',Role='$role') ",$con);
```

with

```
$result = mysql_query("Insert into  table1(`Username`,`Password`,`Role`) values ('$username', '$password','$role') ",$con);
```

You don't have to assign the value to the column on your `INSERT` query as you have done. Just map the values as shown above.

Apart from the above issues... Dissecting your code ..

The main issue with your code is you are doing an `INSERT` but you are expecting a resultset as you have done a SQL `SELECT` which is wrong.

You need to change your code like this..

### The below code is just an illustration to tell you what you had done was actually wrong. Do not use this code ! You first need to migrate to the latest database API provided for you in the side note section.

```
$db_select = mysql_select_db('my_db', $con);
if(isset($_GET['username'],$_GET['password'],$_GET['role']))
{
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['username']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['password']);
$role =     mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['role']);
$result = mysql_query("Insert into  table1(`Username`,`Password`,`Role`) values ('$username', '$password','$role') ",$con);
if (!$result)
{
    die (mysql_error());
}
else
{
    echo "Record Inserted";
}
mysql_close($con);
}
```

---

**`SideNote`**

The (`mysql_*`) extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead,the `MySQLi` or `PDO_MySQL` extension should be used. Switching to `PreparedStatements` is even more better to ward off SQL Injection attacks !

Comment: Guys I have a database named 'name' and 'my_db ' by using mysql_query 
But as what u guys suggested i have used mysqli_query,,,during the execution it says no database exists/ mysqli_select_db($con,"name");/

Comment: @downvoters and mods, care to explain what happened with this answer, why was it downvoted twice? why was comment thread deleted?

Comment: @DevZer0, That is because a lot drama happened ;)

Comment: please improve your answer and add sufficient escaping. then i will +1 it

Comment: @DevZer0, Yeah did it.

Answer (score 1):

For a INSERT query the return value isn't a resource, it's a TRUE on success or FALSE on error.

A resource is returned for a SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN query.

Answer (score 0):

this is your solution change your query to

`$result = mysql_query("Insert into  table1(Username,Password,Role) values ('$username', '$password','$role') ",$con);`

Answer (score -1):

your query should be like this

```
$result = mysql_query("Insert into  table1(Username,Password,Role) values ('$username', '$password','$role') ",$con);
```

**NOTE:** `mysql_*` is deprecated use `mysqli_*` OR `PDO`

Comment: Not my downvote, but your code neglects to escape the variables properly.